# calculate the add of all the numbers in a string sequence

Tags: java

How to find the total number of test cases from a given string :

```
String s = "TestcasePass100TestcaseFail25TestcaseSkipped50";
```

OutPut=175

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We request you to show your effort first, what you have done and tried so far. We can not answer direct question where there are no efforts. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8+ you can just use :

```
String str = "TestcasePass100TestcaseFail25TestcaseSkipped50";
int total = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D")) // split with non degits
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()) // Java 11 you use .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty))
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf) // convert each element to an Integer
        .sum(); // sum the result, the output: 175
```